# Python Pickle file gets erased without error

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, pickle

I have 3 pickle files to which add data separately through 3 variables `recipeNames = []`, `ingredients = {}`, `procedure = {}`, given below is the way I check if the file exists and load the data. Whenever I rn my program the 3 variables are empty when they are printed after loading.

```
recipeNames = []
ingredients = {}
procedure = {}
# --------------------------------------

if path.exists('RecipeNames.pickle'):
    with open("RecipeNames.pickle", "rb") as r:
        recipeNames = pickle.load(r)
        print(recipeNames)

if not path.exists('RecipeNames.pickle'):
    with open("RecipeNames.pickle", "wb") as r:
        recipeNames = []
        pickle.dump(recipeNames, r)

# ---------------------------------------

if path.exists('Ingredients.pickle'):
    with open("Ingredients.pickle", "rb") as i:
        ingredients = pickle.load(i)
        print(ingredients)

if not path.exists("Ingredients.pickle"):
    with open("Ingredients.pickle", "wb") as i:
        pickle.dump(ingredients, i)

# ---------------------------------------

if path.exists('Procedure.pickle'):
    with open("Procedure.pickle", "rb") as p:
        procedure = pickle.load(p)
        print(procedure)

if not path.exists("Procedure.pickle"):
    with open("Procedure.pickle", "wb") as p:
        pickle.dump(procedure, p)
```

I have a function that I use to save the data whenever required, it is given below.

```
def save():
    with open("RecipeNames.pickle", "ab") as r:
        pickle.dump(recipeNames, r)
    with open("Ingredients.pickle", "ab") as i:
        pickle.dump(ingredients, i)
    with open("Procedure.pickle", "ab") as p:
        pickle.dump(procedure, p)
```

Comment: Have your examined the pickle files for their size to see how much data is actually written to them?

Comment: @Samuel Dominguez All of them seem to have 1 kb, I opened one of them with notepad and saw some squigglies(unreadable binary). But if data is being written and stored why is it not being loaded?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Ideally, that handles only one file (instead of three) but stores some well-defined data to it (via a literal).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The problem is occuring in all 3 so essentially you could just examine the first block of code i.e. for ```RecipeNames.pickle```. So please just look at the first block and my save function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are writing a pickle file for empty objects, but you save new data using append. So, when you load the pickle file, it loads the first pickle dump which happens to be empty data saved earlier, disregarding the fact that the same file contains more pickle dumps ahead.

In short, just using 'wb' instead of 'ab' in your `save` function should solve your problem if I am correct.

Comment: Thank you, although I still didn;t understand why I'm using wb. Isn't wb supposed to be used to overwrite everything in the previous file?

Comment: Yes, wb does overrite a file. Let's talk about ingredients list. We read it from disk into memory, modify it in memory, and finally save the whole thing back to the disk, overriting existing file. On disk it is saved with all information neccessary to recreate the list, not just the items in it. We leave the task to save modified list to pickle, not append information ourselves. Hope, this clears things a bit more.